# How to Make \textgreek Bold and Italicized Using the Electrum Package

Tags: fonts, bold, italic, italic-correction

I am working on a project that makes use of the `electrum` package, and which, from time to time, I would like to be able to make bold some Greek using the `\textgreek` command. Alas, I have not been able to make the text bold.

In fact, neither can I italicize a greek word as the following MWE shows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{electrum}

\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\Large
\noindent \textit{\textbf{\textgreek{n{<o}son}}} \\
\textbf{\textgreek{n{<o}son}} \\
\textbf{\textit{some italicized and bold english words}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, both the bold and italicize commands seem to work fine with `electrum` for english text.

Does anyone know what the problem might be and how to correct it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, the Greek font got changed.  So here, I reset it to `artemisia`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{electrum}

\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

  \usepackage{substitutefont}
  \substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{artemisia}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\Large
\textgreek{n{<o}son}\\
\noindent \textit{\textbf{\textgreek{n{<o}son}}} \\
\textbf{\textgreek{n{<o}son}} \\
\textbf{\textit{some italicized and bold english words}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works very nicely.